# Failed to boot after installing dracut on Ubuntu 22.04 with zfs file system

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, grub, zfs, dracut

I installed (sudo apt install dracut, did not change any configuration files) dracut on my Ubuntu 22.04 and rebooted. Now I get the message

```
dracut: FATAL: Don't know hot to handle 'root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_m6r2ku'
dracut: Refuses to continue
reboot: System halted
```

How can I fix this problem? I already tried to change the line root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_m6r2ku to root=ZFS:auto in grub by pressing 'e' in grub menu and booting, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because somehow your grub2-mkconfig ran with an unmodified `10_linux` script. The line `dracut` complains ought to work, but the current version of `zfs-dracut` plus various complex issues with grub don't allow it to work.

For a quick test, just interrupt the boot process, edit the menu selection, and remove the `root=` clause. Your system should boot normally.

---

If the above works, you can try this for a permanent fix:

1. Carefully review your modifications to `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`.
2. Run `blkid` to show the UUID of your EFI boot partition.
3. Make sure that UUID is configured in `/etc/fstab` to mount `/boot/efi`.
4. Run mount to confirm that `/boot/efi` is in fact mounted there.
5. Re-run `grub2-mkconfig`.

I'm also running Ubuntu Server with ZFS and I had some issues with `zfs-dracut` myself, so I decided to not install it the second time I set it up. Haven't had any issues since.

Comment: Hi. I tried to do so. It doesn't boots successfully, but at least I got a command prompt. 
`[FAILED] Failed to start Switch Root.
Generating "run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"
Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue
etc`
And then I got :/root# invitation. My SDD are not actually mounted, most commands are not available, no /boot.

Comment: I tried to #blkid, and then #mount /dev/sdc3, but received
 `unknown filesystem type 'zfs_member'`

Comment: @ubuntulinuxxuser987 For the first part, what's the output of `journalctl -x --no-pager --catalog`? For the second part, I'll have to update my answer.

Comment: @ubuntulinuxxuser987 Is it a wholly fresh installation of Ubuntu + ZFS? Like, do you have any data you have to recover from the drive you're trying to mount? If not, it may be just as good to nuke the whole thing and start from scratch... if you have to recover data, let me know and I'll try to help you.

Comment: Installation is about 2 month old, I have separate /home folder, luckily. journalctl  says something like "Failed to switch root: Specified switch root path 'sysroot' does not seem to be an OS tree. os-release file is missing. Failed to start Switch Root".

Comment: Also I cannot mount vfat with efi in this shell, it complains about IO charset iso8859-1 not found. depmod does nothing

Comment: I don't have any important data except in /home, so I guess I'll just reinstall, if no one suggests a solution. Thanks.

Comment: So it worked before you installed `dracut`? Have you tried just uninstalling `dracut`? (Just as a reminder/side note: Debian based distros, which includes Ubuntu, use `initramfs` and not `dracut`)

Comment: I don't know how to uninstall dracut :) Because I cannot mount neither / neither /boot partitions in emergency mode. Maybe, I can use Live usb somehow?